# How to remove big spaces in my scraped texts?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to remove big spaces from the code result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://www.rucoyonline.com/characters/Something' 
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'character-table table table-bordered')
print(table.get_text())
```

Result after running code :

```
Character Information




Name
Something


Level
28


Last online

                    about 6 years ago



Born
September 03, 2016
```

`string()` is not working, I think it's because `beautifulsoup`

Comment: there are likely 'big spaces' in your target html.   what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What do you consider a "big space"? Any two consecutive whitespace characters (including line breaks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One line answer:**

```
print("\n".join([s for s in table.get_text().split("\n") if s]))
```

**Output:**

```
Character Information
Name
Something
Level
28
Last online
                    about 6 years ago
Born
September 03, 2016
```

**And to remove trailing and leading spaces**

```
print("\n".join([s.strip() for s in table.get_text().split("\n") if s]))
```

**Output:**

```
Character Information
Name
Something
Level
28
Last online
about 6 years ago
Born
September 03, 2016
```

**Alternatively you can utilize `BeautifulSoup`'s `get_text()` to do the same:**

```
print(table.get_text("\n", strip=True))
```

**Output:**

```
Character Information
Name
Something
Level
28
Last online
about 6 years ago
Born
September 03, 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `BeautifulSoup`. You can do this,

```
table_values = [item.text.strip() for item in table.find_all('tr')]
for item in table_values:
    print(item.replace('\n', ''))
```

Output

```
Character Information
NameSomething
Level28
Last online                    about 6 years ago
BornSeptember 03, 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `regex` or `join()` of `list comprehension` results - Simply use standard parameters of [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
table.get_text('\n',strip=True)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.rucoyonline.com/characters/Something' 
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'character-table table table-bordered')
print(table.get_text('\n',strip=True))
```

##### Output

```
Character Information
Name
Something
Level
28
Last online
about 6 years ago
Born
September 03, 2016
```